# Flink Job on EMR Cluster "GC overhead limit exceeded"

Tags: garbage-collection, apache-flink, amazon-emr

EMR-Flink job is showing error  "GC overhead limit exceeded error". The EMR cluster is created within VPC with default EMR roles. Hadoop and Flink options are selected from advanced option (I tried different versions of Hadoop and Flink)

Step method is used to submit the custom jar with the set of arguments. Job reads the data from Aurora DB

Problem: The job executes successfully when the read request has less number of rows from Aurora DB but as the number of rows goes up to millions, I start getting "GC overhead limit exceeded error". I am using JDBC driver for Aurora DB connection. On my local machine, I don't face any error and everything goes fine regardless of data size in read request.

The exact error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 8344"...
```

Tried Solution:
1: I tried to solve the problem by using this link:https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-outofmemory-gc-overhead-limit-error/ .

2: I also tried to provide flink configuration at the time of cluster creation such as

```
taskmanager.heap.mb:13926
jobmanager.heap.mb:13926
taskmanager.memory.preallocate:true
taskmanager.memory.off-heap:true
```

3: I also tried other options and added other settings flink configuration but nothing is working for me.

Comment: Can it simply be that the amount of data you read from DB is big and you do not have enough memory for it?

Comment: Are you using batch or streaming? Could you create a heap dump?

Comment: @ArvidHeise, It is a batch job and the problem is solved and solution can be seen in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the hadoop memory as seen below

============= Java processes for user hadoop =============
8228 com.amazonaws.elasticmapreduce.statepusher.StatePusher -Dlog4j.defaultInitOverride
4522 aws157.instancecontroller.Main -Xmx1024m -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -Dlog4j.defaultInitOverride
=========== End java processes for user hadoop ===========

The following configuration worked for me and solved my problem

```
[
  {
"Classification": "hadoop-env",
"Properties": {

},
"Configurations": [
  {
    "Classification": "export",
    "Properties": {
      "HADOOP_HEAPSIZE":"10000"
    },
    "Configurations": [

    ]
  }
]
}
]
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer!